# Aggragate Multiple Columns Using LISTAGG()

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I concatenate the results of a column from multiple rows into a single row? My query is:

```
SELECT id AS "Record ID", ins_type AS "Inspection Type", stat AS "Status"
FROM records
ORDER BY id;
```

Result:

[image: Example]

Where the id is the same, I would like to aggregate any multiple inspection types into a single column, like this:

```
Record ID       Inspection Type                                         Status
B202105148      Final Building, Final Electrical, Framing & Flashing    Approved
B202105143      Roof Framing/Sheathing                                  Approved
```

I am using Oracle Database version 12.1.0.2.0.

I tried using the **LISTAGG()** function:

```
SELECT id AS "Record ID", LISTAGG( ins_type, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ins_type ) AS "Inspection Type", stat AS "Status"
FROM records
ORDER BY id;
```

But I got:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.
```

Comment: What's the expected result if Framing & Flashing isn't Approved?

Comment: @jarlh Null would be expected.

Comment: NULL, where in the result?

Comment: [**ORA-00937**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903): **Cause**: A SELECT list cannot include both a group function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, and an individual column expression, unless the individual column expression is included in a GROUP BY clause.

**Action**: Drop either the group function or the individual column expression from the SELECT list or add a GROUP BY clause that includes all individual column expressions listed.

Comment: If you were a DBMS, what would you return as a value for `status` grouped by `id` if some IDs contain more than one status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed group by

```
SELECT id AS "Record ID", 
LISTAGG( ins_type, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ins_type ) AS "Inspection Type", stat AS "Status"
FROM records
group by id,stat
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244274/aggragate-multiple-columns-using-listagg/71244586#comment125932714_71244274):

> > What's the expected result if Framing & Flashing isn't Approved?
>
> Null would be expected.

You need to either use an aggregation function on the `stat` column or add it to the `GROUP BY` clause. Since you appear to want to only display `Approved` if all the records are `Approved` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT id AS "Record ID", 
       LISTAGG( ins_type, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ins_type ) AS "Inspection Type",
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN stat = 'Approved' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
       THEN 'Approved'
       END AS "Status"
FROM   records
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```